# How to update data using Flutter and Hive DB?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-hive

```
 void deleteTask(int index) {
    setState(() {
      db.toDoList.removeAt(index);
    });
    db.updateDataBase();
  }
```

This is what the delete function looks like. How can I make the edit function for hive using flutter in that manner as above stated?

Comment: what do you mean with "that manner as above stated", can you clarify ?

Comment: do you want to just update an element in your Hive database ?

Comment: @gwhyy yes, please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Hive` database, there is a `get()`, `getAt()` `put()`, `putAt()`, `delete()`, `deleteAt()` methods that are well-documented from it's [official documentation](https://docs.hivedb.dev/).

`Hive` is a key-value based database, there is no `update()` method by default, but you can achieve the same as only with the provided methods (`getAt()` and `putAt()`).

Considering that I have a "stringText" value stored on the `5` index, as we know to get it from a box, we can do the:

```
String valueFromTheBox = box.getAt(5); // "stringText"
```

And, in order to achieve and update this value, we simply need to assign a new value to that `valueFromTheBox` variable and put it again on the same key using `putAt()` like this:

```
valueFromTheBox = "newValueTHatWillBePut";
box.putAt(5);
```

This will literally make an update method, so in order to make a full function that achieves, and based on your case we can do:

```
void updateTask(int index) {
 SetState(() {
  
  dynamic task = db.toDoList.getAt(index); // get previous task
  task = changeSomethingAndReturn(previousTask); // change/edit the task
  db.toDoList.putAt(index, task); // assign the task on same index 
 
  });
  
  db.updateDataBase();

}
```

And you need to replace `changeSomethingAndReturn()` method with your method that takes the task and makes changes over it then returns the new changed one.

Note: I don't recommend letting the dynamic type, since it's not mentioned in your question, I'm using it, but you should specify its type so you prevent getting into errors.

Comment: thank you @Gwhyy and do i have to add the prviousTask thing its kind of a hassle

Comment: using Hive, you have no other option to update an element than getting it, then make changes on it, then put it again on the same index.

Comment: may I asking you why you need to use setState on this ?

Comment: No reason if there is a other way please tell (I'm a 14 year old beginner)

Comment: The Hive package can be combined with the ValueListenableWidget which could listen automatically to box  changes, so whenever any change like using `deleteAt`, `putAt()` and this `update()` methods, automatically it will update state based on it without needing to use setState(() {}) every time.

Comment: check it from here https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/hive_in_flutter?id=valuelistenable